# Change class via JQuery not working on Websocket message

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, thymeleaf, spring-websocket

I've been stuck on a small problem for a while now. I have spring websockets via stomp client set up and I receive the message and try to call a simple removeClass() / addClass() / css() operation on a specific element.

Here's the relevant code:

```
// Function called on page load
function connectToConfirm() {
    var sck = new SockJS('/endpoint');
    sClient = Stomp.over(sck); 
    sClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        sClient.subscribe('/test', function(readyConfirmation) {
            setReady(JSON.parse(readyConfirmation.body));
        });
    });
}

function setReady(content) {
    $('#readyIndicator-'+content.id)
        .addClass('fa-check')
        .removeClass('fa-times')
        .css('color', 'green');
    console.log("ID: " +content.id); 
    // Displays the correct id and shows the function gets called
    console.log("Object exists?: " +$('#readyIndicator-'+content.id).length);
    // Displays "1", therefore an element by that id exists.

}
```

HTML with Thymeleaf. ${group} object gets added via a HandlerInterceptorAdapter implementation and the values are displayed correctly:

```
<tr th:each="user: ${group.members}">
    <td width="80%" th:text="${user.username}">Username</td>
    <td width="20%">
        <i th:id="readyIndicator- + ${user.id}" class="fa fa-times"
                                style="color: red;"></i>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have a button that sends a message to the server and it gets returned properly, e.g.:

```
>>> SEND
destination:/app/myMapping/foo
content-length:20
```

.. and I get the reply:

```
<<< MESSAGE
destination:/test
content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
subscription:sub-1
message-id:ffbazdj4-82
content-length:84

{"id":"123", .. , ..}
```

So yeah, the function gets called but the class does not get updated, even though the element exists. I'm really lost why this could ever happen. To make matters worse, I have a similar implementation in another project that works just fine. The only difference I really see is that the object gets added directly to the model in the controller instead of in the postHandle() method.